# Use bind1st or bind2nd?

Tags: c++, stl

```
vector<int> vwInts;
vector<int> vwIntsB;

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    vwInts.push_back(i);

transform(vwInts.begin(), vwInts.end(), inserter(vwIntsB, vwIntsB.begin()),
        bind1st(plus<int>(), 5)); // method one

transform(vwInts.begin(), vwInts.end(), inserter(vwIntsB, vwIntsB.begin()),
        bind2nd(plus<int>(), 5)); // method two
```

I know the usage difference between bind1st and bind2nd and both method one and method two provide the expected results for me.

Is it true that there is no big difference in this case (i.e. usage of transform) so  that I can use either bind1st or bind2nd?

Since, all examples I saw so far always use the method two. I would like to know whether or not bind1st and bind2nd in above case are same.

Comment: I would recommend you to look into boost::bind if you haven't. It is more flexible and more powerful than bind1st and bind2nd.

Answer (score 7):

`bind1st` binds the first parameter of `plus<int>()` functor, and `bind2nd` binds the second parameter. In case of `plus<int>`, it doesn't make any difference, as `10+20` and `20+10` are same.

But if you do that with `minus<int>`, it would make difference, as `10-20` and `20-10` aren't same. Just try doing that.

Illustration:

```
int main () {
  auto p1 = bind1st(plus<int>(),10);
  auto p2 = bind2nd(plus<int>(),10);
  cout << p1(20) << endl;
  cout << p2(20) << endl;

  auto m1 = bind1st(minus<int>(),10);
  auto m2 = bind2nd(minus<int>(),10);
  cout << m1(20) << endl;
  cout << m2(20) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 30
 30
-10
 10
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/IfSdt

Answer (score 4):

`bind1st` binds the first parameter of a function while `bind2nd` binds the second parameter. Since the two parameter types are the same in this case and `operator+` is symmetrical it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, they'd translate respectively to 5 + a and a + 5, which gets compiled to exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case

```
bind1st()
```

and

```
bind2nd()
```

are **same**.

Thus is because, `plus()` binary function operator looks like below

```
plus(arg1, arg2)
```

So, when you use `bind1st(plus<int>(), 5)` the call to plus would look as under

```
plus(5, vwInts)
```

so, above will add every element of vector with a value `5`

And when you use `bind2nd(plus<int>(), 5)` the call to plus would look as under

```
plus(vwInts, 5)
```

so, above will add every element of vector with a value `5`.

Hence **both are same in your case**