# How passing arguments using std::mem_fun

Tags: c++, algorithm, foreach

I would know if there is a way to pass arguments using std::mem_fun ?
I want to precise that I can have as much arguments as possible and a lot of member functions.
The problem is that I'm on an old standard and I'm looking for a full stl way so boost isn't allowed as answer even if I know I could do it easily =/

Here is a little illustration of how I wanna use it :

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

// Class declaration
//
struct Interface {
   virtual void run() = 0;
   virtual void do_something(int) = 0;
   virtual void do_func(int, int) = 0;
};

struct A : public Interface {
   void run() { cout << "Class A : run" << endl; }
   void do_something(int foo) { cout << "Class A : " << foo << endl; }
   void do_func(int foo, int bar) { cout << "Class A : " << foo << " " << bar << endl; }
};

struct B : public Interface {
   void run() { cout << "Class B : run" << endl; }
   void do_something(int foo) { cout << "Class B : " << foo << endl; }
   void do_func(int foo, int bar) { cout << "Class B : " << foo << " " << bar << endl; }
};

// Main
//
int main() {
   // Create A and B
   A a;
   B b;

   // Insert it inside a list
   std::list<Interface *> list;
   list.push_back(&a);
   list.push_back(&b);

   // This works
   std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), std::mem_fun(&Interface::run));

   // But how to give arguments for those member funcs ?
   std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), std::mem_fun(&Interface::do_something));
   std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), std::mem_fun(&Interface::do_func));
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `std::bind` via `std::bind1st` and `std::bind2nd`

```
std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(),
              std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun(&Interface::do_something),1) // because 1st is this
             );
```

Unfortunately, the standard does not help for the two arguments version and you need to write your own:

```
struct MyFunctor
{
    void (Interface::*func)(int,int);
    int         a;
    int         b;

    MyFunctor(void (Interface::*f)(int,int), int a, int b): func(f), a(a), b(b) {}

    void operator()(Interface* i){ (i->*func)(a,b);}
};

std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(),
              MyFunctor(&Interface::do_func, 1, 2)
             );
```

#### Lambda version

The original answer was good back in 2012 when Lambda's had just been added to the standard and few compilers were C++11 compliant yet. Now 8 years later most compilers are C++11 compliant and we can use this to make these things much simpler.

```
// Binding 1 parameter
std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(),
              [](auto act){act->do_something(1);})

// Binding 2 parameters
std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(),
              [](auto act){act->do_func(1, 2);})
```

Comment: To find out the difference between `std::bind1st` and `std::bind2nd` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6863747/5506988

Comment: @Mark There is no difference (apart from the obvious of which parameter bound). Note: This question is about calling "methods" with two parameters, unfortunately this is not possible as the first parameter is used for the object and only the second can be used to be bind a parameter. Note: This is different from functions as they have no object required to bind.

Comment: @Mark This is also no longer relevant as Lambdas allow us to do this much more simply nowadays.

Comment: what brought me here is a member function which requires one argument, but it's a default argument. It wouldn't compile with `std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(),std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&Interface::do_something),1);` only J.N.'s (last answer) worked. But I'm still wondering why. The lambda will solve my issue but im curious now.

Answer (score 1):

See `std::bind1st` and `std::bind2nd`. They're fairly clumsy and ugly to use, but if you insist on only using what's present in C++03 without any additions at all, they're pretty much all that's available.

Edit: when/if I need to do this, I usually do it with a small functor class instead of using `std::bind1st` and/or `std::bind2nd`. This isn't ultimately much different from what those generate, but (IMO) it's generally more readable.

```
template<class T>
class invoke_do_something { 
    int value;
public:
    adder(int x) : value(x) {}
    void operator()(T &t) { 
        t.do_something(value);
    }
};

std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), invoke_do_something(1));
```

My own take, however, is that most of the time this is kind of a band-aid. It happens constantly using `for_each`. I usually find that with some thought, I can find a more suitable algorithm, which frequently eliminates the need for anything on this order at all.

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you put an example of how to use it ? I can't get it work..

Comment: I suppose I could, but 1) @LokiAstari already has, so it wouldn't add much, and 2) I never use them myself. I decided long ago they weren't worth the trouble. In the (surprisingly rare) situation where I need that sort of thing, I write a small functor class to deal with it. Thankfully, in C++11, it's easy to eliminate that too.

Comment: @kl94: I've done a bit of editing to add an example of the general approach I usually take when I feel the need for this. I hasten to emphasize the final point in the edit though: most of the time, more careful algorithm selection eliminates the whole problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I feel like if I've a lot of members funcs, I'll have to create as much invoke class as I have members funcs =/ I looked for a more generic way but as you said, lastest version c++ version avoid my problem. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can by binding:

```
using std::placeholders::_1
int a;
std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), std::bind(&Interface::do_something, _1, a));
```

Comment: He's on "an old standard", i.e. 98 or 03. This is C++11.

Comment: @MSalters : noticed that, though, C++11 is sooooo last year.

Answer (score 0):

Since `c++20`, you do not need `std::bind` and family. You can do like this using [`std::mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn). Note that `std::mem_fun` is not available from `c++20`

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Foo {
    void display_number(int i, char ch, std::string s) {
        std::cout << "number: " << i << " character: " << ch << " string: " << s << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;

    auto print_num = std::mem_fn(&Foo::display_number);
    print_num(f, 42, 'a', "Hello!");
}
```

Output :

```
number: 42 character: a string: Hello!
```